# Transformation of a Random Variable

Tags: statistics, transformation, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

We have a  random variable $x$ with p.d.f. $\sqrt{\dfrac{\theta}{\pi x}}\exp(-x\theta)$, $x>0$ and $\theta$ a positive parameter.

We are required to show that $2\theta x$  has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $1$ degree of freedom and deduce that, if $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are independent r.v. with this p.d.f., then $2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

Using  transformation $y=2\theta x$ I found  the pdf of
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}y^{-1/2}e^{-y/2}.$$
How do I find the distribution of $2\theta\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$? Do I need to find the likelihood function  (which contains $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$) first? How do I recognise the degrees of freedom of  this distribution (Is it $n$ because it involves $x_1,\dots,x_n$, i.e. $n$ random variables?

Comment: I would suggest reformatting your question to make it more readable: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok, many thanks to the editor for reformatting my question. Hope anyone has any helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The probability density function of a random variable $Z$ which follows the chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is given by
 $$f_Z(z)=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma{(\frac{n}{2})}}z^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{z}{2}}$$
for $z>0$.

You already  derived the $pdf$ of the transformed random variable $Y=2\theta X$. By matching that $pdf$ of $Y$ with the $pdf$ of $Z$, you can notice that $Y$ is actually following chi-square distribution with $d.f.$ n (where n=1).

Again $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variable implies that $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ also independent random variable.

Note that, sum of independent chi- square distribution is also a chi-square distribution with $d.f.$ equals to sum of the corresponding degree of freedoms.

Using the above result you can say that the distribution of  $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is chi-square distribution with $d.f.$  n.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome.